# python2.7 print values in list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a question to print values in list.

```
import time
strings = time.strftime("%Y,%m,%d")
t = strings.split(',')
date = [int(x) for x in t]
print date
```

then result is

```
[2016,5,15]
```

But I want to print values in date like this

```
20160515
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why not just generate it in that format in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with doing it like this:

```
>>> strings = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
>>> strings
'20160515'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't just do:

```
time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
```

---

On the other hand, if you are just looking for a way to concatenate elements of a list, use `join`:

```
In [110]: s = time.strftime("%Y,%m,%d")

In [111]: sl = s.split(',')

In [112]: ''.join(sl)
Out[112]: '20160515'
```

Answer (score 1):

you must just change your code :

```
import time
strings = time.strftime("%Y%m%d") # delete ','
print strings
```